# Will xVal work if the attributes are defined on Interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, xval

I'm wondering if anyone knows if xVal will work as expected if I define my system.componentmodel.dataannotations attributes on interfaces that are implemented by my model classes, instead of directly on the concrete model classes.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    [Required] [StringLength(30)]
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then in my model class there wouldn't be any validation attributes...

```
public class FooFoo : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to validate a FooFoo with xVal, will it use the attribs from its interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment the `xVal.RuleProviders.DataAnnotationsRuleProvider` only looks at properties defined on the model class itself. You can see this in the method `GetRulesFromProperty` in the rule provider base class `PropertyAttributeRuleProviderBase`:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<Rule> GetRulesFromProperty(
    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
{
    return from att in propertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<TAttribute>()
           from validationRule in MakeValidationRulesFromAttribute(att)
           where validationRule != null
           select validationRule;
}
```

The `propertyDescriptor` parameter represents a property in your model class and its [`Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.memberdescriptor.attributes.aspx) property represents only the attributes defined directly on the property itself.

However, you could of course extend `DataAnnotationsRuleProvider` and override the appropriate method to make it do what you want: extract validation attributes from implemented interfaces. You then register your rule provider with xVal:

```
ActiveRuleProviders.Providers.Clear();
ActiveRuleProviders.Providers.Add(new MyDataAnnotationsRuleProvider());
ActiveRuleProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomRulesProvider());
```

To get attributes from properties in implemented interfaces, you should extend `DataAnnotationsRuleProvider` and override `GetRulesFromTypeCore`. It gets a parameter of type [`System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) that has a method [`GetInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!! I guess the next question is: Is there an easy way to iterate through the interfaces a class implements? You would need to do this in order to get PropertyDescriptors for each property on the interfaces.

Comment: I added some more info on how to get the implemented interfaces of a type.

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward, Thanks a bunch!!